# How to disable button when text box is clear?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to enable textbox when user start to print on it end disable button when text box is empty.

here is my text box and button:

```
   <button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="SaveNewLayer()" disabled>save</button>
   <input type="text" id="newLayerName" placeholder="name" value="" />
```

Here is the code that I use:

```
function setElementsDisabled() {
    $('#newLayerName').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length != 0)
            $('#btnSaveLayer').attr('disabled', false);
        else
            $('#btnSaveLayer').attr('disabled', true);
    })
}
```

From function above you can see that, when user start to enter text in text box butten enabled and when the user remove from text box button disabled.

And it works perfect!!!

But when I clear button programmatically using this jquery code:

```
  $("#newLayerName").val('');
```

The text from textbox is removed but, button is not disabled.

Any idea how to change my function `setElementsDisabled` so that when text box is empty the button is disabled?

Comment: maybe `<` instead of `!=` and what you can do as well is when you trigger the empty button also set `disabled true` in the same call. This way your the button is automatically blocked when somebody clears the input.

Comment: View answer I have given below

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try use `$('#newLayerName').trigger("keyup")` to achive what you want. Example below.

```js
function setElementsDisabled() {
  $('#newLayerName').keyup(function() {
      $('#btnSaveLayer').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length == 0);
  })
}
setElementsDisabled()

$("#clear").click(function() {
  $("#newLayerName").val('').trigger("keyup");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="SaveNewLayer()" disabled>save</button>
<input type="text" id="newLayerName" placeholder="name" value="" />

<button id="clear"> clear</button>
```

Comment: should be using prop

Comment: This code could still be heavily optimized by caching `$('#btnSaveLayer')` and `$('#newLayerName')`, and also rewriting the `disabled` logic in one simple line (see my answer)

Comment: You haven't cached the button. Besides, instead of building a `$(this)` jQuery object at every keystroke, it would be much more elegant and efficient to read the keyup event value with `e.target.event`. Besides, why is OP writing the keyup binding in a function, then calling this function? This code is still unnecessarily heavy. I have written a full proper solution, but it's buried down below so it doesn't get any upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script

```js
$("#newLayerName").keyup(function(e){
   check($(this));
})

$("#newLayerName").change(function(){
   check($("#newLayerName"));
})

function check(obj){
   if($(obj).val().length==0){
    $("#btnSaveLayer").prop("disabled",true);
   }
   else{
   $("#btnSaveLayer").prop("disabled",false);
   }
}
$("#newLayerName").val("Hello");

check($("#newLayerName"));

setTimeout(function(){
$("#newLayerName").val("").change();
},3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="SaveNewLayer()" disabled>save</button>
   <input type="text" id="newLayerName" placeholder="name" value="" />
```

Comment: Hes asking how to make it work when he use `$("#newLayerName").val('')` to clear the textbox with

Comment: You're calling a `check` function, with contains uncached buttons,  10 times a second. That's a _lot_ of operations and DOM calls. This code is heavy and could be greatly optimized.

Comment: But you are doing empty your textbox using console. How will you that that has been empty

Comment: Even if you try change event still that will not work

Comment: Accept if you got answer

Comment: @MilanChheda you can trim that, you can replace in change event *if($(obj).val().trim().length==0){*

Answer (score 1):

You can add this

```
 if ($('#newLayerName').val().length != 0)
                $('#btnSaveLayer').attr('disabled', false);
            else
                $('#btnSaveLayer').attr('disabled', true);
```

in a seperate function and call the same method programatically when you are clearing the text box

Comment: And you can even cache the button and write all this logic as a simple one-liner (see my answer).

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes Similar to a Trigger

Comment: Nothing to do with the trigger. I'm talking about the `true-false` logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually trigger a `keyup` event, and also heavily optimize this code (cache buttons, one-liner `disabled` logic, use of `prop` instead of `attr`, reading the event's value instead of building a `$(this)` object, etc.) :

```js
const $btnSaveLayer = $('#btnSaveLayer'),
   $newLayerName = $("#newLayerName")

$('#newLayerName').keyup( e => {
     $btnSaveLayer.prop('disabled', !e.target.value.length);
})

$("#clearBtn").click( () => {
 $newLayerName.val('').trigger("keyup");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="SaveNewLayer()" disabled>save</button>
   <input type="text" id="newLayerName" placeholder="name" value="" /> 
<button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever programmatically call `$("#newLayerName").val('');` instead of it you can call `$("#newLayerName").val('').keyup();`. Trigger `keyup` event after clear data.

```js
$("#newLayerName").keyup(function(e){
   if($(this).val().length==0){
    $("#btnSaveLayer").prop("disabled",true);
   }
   else{
   $("#btnSaveLayer").prop("disabled",false);
   }
})

function programaticallyClear() {
 $("#newLayerName").val('').keyup();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="SaveNewLayer()" disabled>save</button>
   <input type="text" id="newLayerName" placeholder="name" value="" />

<button id="programaticallyClearButton" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="programaticallyClear()" >programaticallyClearButton</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. We need to use `keyup` event on the input element.
2. We need to check the value entered the input. Spaces should not be allowed (obvious)
3. Event will be fired on click on `clear` and will call the same keyup trigger

```js
$('#newLayerName').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#btnSaveLayer').prop('disabled', $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0);
});

$("#clear").click(function() {
  $("#newLayerName").val('').trigger("keyup");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="SaveNewLayer()" disabled>save</button>
<input type="text" id="newLayerName" placeholder="name" value="" />

<button id="clear"> clear</button>
```